# How to save an object in Entity Framework while using a database generated option for one of its columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have a webpage in my project where a user signs up with their info and that info is sent to my controller by an api call in the frontend. In my controller, I am trying to create an object with the data, but the only way to create the object is to use a hardcoded id in my parameters. I need the id to be created automatically without obviously hardcoding it in.

**Controller**

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string username, string password, string email, string role)
{
    int id = 1;
    Users user = new Users(id, username, password, email, role);
    _repository.CreateUser(user);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace IssueTracker.Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string role { get; set; }

        public Users(int id, string username, string password, string email, string role)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;
            this.role = role;
        }

        public Users()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
using IssueTracker.Models;

namespace IssueTracker.Data
{
    public interface IIssueTrackerRepo
    {
        bool SaveChanges();
        //IEnumerable<Command> GetAllCommands();
        //Command GetCommandById(int id);
        void CreateUser(Users cmd);
        //void UpdateCommand(Command cmd);
        //void DeleteCommand(Command cmd);
    }
}
```

**Interface Implementation**

```
using System;
using IssueTracker.Models;
namespace IssueTracker.Data
{
    public class SqlUsersRepo: IIssueTrackerRepo
    {
        private readonly UsersContext _context;

        public SqlUsersRepo(UsersContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void CreateUser(Users user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }
            
            _context.Users.Add(user);
        }

        public bool SaveChanges()
        {
            return (_context.SaveChanges() >= 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**signup.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const Signup = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [role, setRole] = useState()

    const post = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
                password: password,
                email: email,
                role: role
            }),
        };
        fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/IssueTracker", requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {

            })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <body>
                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <TextField onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                    <br>
                    </br>
                    <TextField onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                    <br>
                    </br>
                    <TextField onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                    <br>
                    </br>
                    <TextField onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                    <br>
                    </br>
                    <Button onClick={() => post()}> Sign Up</Button>
                </form>
            </body>
        </div>
    );
}



export default Signup;
```

Comment: It seems your choice to make a constructor that demands an `id` when the DB will generte it; remove the parameter. You forgot to post the definition of whatever _repository is. Also, don't name classes in the plural. If they're a collection, suffix the name with `Collection`. Don't name public members in all lowercase. If you're facing some JSON serializing issue, use attributes etc to specify how properties should be named for ser rather than bending C# naming conventions

Comment: If the `Id` is database generated - you should ***NOT*** set it to a specific value yourself - leave it alone and let the database assign the identity value to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `id` parameter from your constructor -

```
public Users(string username, string password, string email, string role)
{
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.role = role;
}
```

The annotation -

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

will handle the creation of an `Id` for you at the database end. Just create the entity without an `Id` and save it -

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(string username, string password, string email, string role)
{
    Users user = new Users(id, username, password, email, role);
    _repository.CreateUser(user);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT:**
To fix further issues you've mentioned in the comment, do the followings -

- on the client end don't `JSON.stringify` the body -

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        email: email,
        role: role
    }
};
```

- at the Api end change your Post method as -

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]User user)
{
    _repository.CreateUser(user);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

The built-in `ModelBinding` feature will create the user entity for you behind the scene, based on the json object you have passed in the body of the request.

Note: For this to work, the json object's property names should match the `User` entity's property names.

Comment: @MPagan, You have it already placed as I can see. On the `id` property of the `Users` class.

Comment: Ok that solves that problem. Now im getting ```Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'email', table 'IssueTrackerDB.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.```. Wondering if the data is getting correctly received from the frontend. I provided my frontend code above.

Comment: That's because you annotated the `email` property with `[Required]`. So the database will not allow a null value for that field. Make sure you are receiving a non-null value for `email` parameter.

Comment: Oh so I do need email as required. When I test the webpage, I am entering in all four values in the textboxes including email. That data isnt getting received correctly im guessing in the backend

Comment: @MPagan Have you found the source of issue with `email` value?

Comment: I haven’t yet. I did some debugging though & saw that not only email but all the other contents of the object contain null right after the object is created. So it has to be something wrong with how I am taking in that data in my controller. I also found out you can just take in the model in the parameters, and it maps out the text box values to the column values. I don’t know how to make that work though

Comment: @MPagan Check the `EDIT` section in my answer.

Comment: user still comes up as null even by using frombody, and the names I am sending in my body match the names in my model class so I'm wondering what it could be

Comment: @MPagan Have you removed the `JSON.stringify` from client code? If so, check your browser's Network tab to see what object is being passed in the request body.

Comment: yes I removed ```JSON.stringify```. I provided the object that is being passed in above in my post.

Comment: @MPagan Your request body should look like this - `{ username: "alice", password: "mypassword", email: "alice@gmail.com", role: "admin" }`. Something is wrong on your client side. Try to find out  :)

Comment: so that is ```JSON.stringify``` lol so why did I have to remove it in the first place? Putting ```JSON.stringify``` back in worked. The object now shows up in my database. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MPagan Bad diagnostics on my part then, sorry. In Angular I never use `JSON.stringify` on request body. Glad I could help  :)